# Fees with Coinbase

Tags: ether, coinbase

I am new to investing in Etherum and Coinbase. I know with credit cards there is a 3.75% fee for buying. Does it seem like with direct bank transfer there isn't? Is this true?

Also, how are taxes calculated with earnings here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transaction fees vary with location. Taxes definitely do. But I'm not a tax lawyer.

Here's a link to the Coinbase pricing page, where they list the percentage fees based on location and payment method:
https://support.coinbase.com/customer/portal/articles/2109597-buy-sell-bank-transfer-fees

Comment: Thanks @Eric I see that there is a 3-5 days waiting period for using bank transfer. During the 3-5 days if prices go up and down, do I pay at the initial price? Or the price when they receive the money (3-5 days later)?

Comment: In my experience you pay the price associated with the initial exchange rate

Comment: Last question, would you trust Coinbase with your bank info

Comment: Yeah. They have the most regulation of any exchange that I know of. If they screw up they'd be facing a pretty serious class-action lawsuit. I just wouldn't keep any Bitcoin/Ethereum/Litecoin in Coinbase's wallet for too long for a myriad of reasons. After you receive the coins, I'd send them to a wallet off of the exchange

Comment: Basically if your government suddenly says crypto is illegal or shutters Coinbase, you still have control of your funds without relying on a third-party :)